# PrimeFaces markup remains after navigation in Liferay 7.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay, liferay-7, senna.js

I've noticed that when I navigate via GET from a page with certain PrimeFaces components, the markup of these components will appear in the upper left-hand corner of the next page.

This problem has happened with the following components (and probably others):

- `p:tooltip`
- `p:columnToggler`
- `p:notifiactionBar`
- `p:selectOneMenu`
- `p:autoComplete`
- `p:confirmDialog`
- `p:dialog`
- `p:draggable`
- `p:menuButton`
- `p:selectCheckboxMenu`
- `p:selectOneMenu`
- `p:splitButton`

Is there any way I can stop this markup from appearing after navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update: This issue has been verified as a bug in the Liferay Faces project and has been fixed as part of Bridge Ext 5.0.3: [FACES-3328](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-3328).

#### Explanation

This problem is due to an incompatibility between PrimeFaces (which was initially designed for webapps) and Liferay 7.0/SennaJS/Portlets. PrimeFaces assumes that it is being used in a webapp environment where it has control over all markup on the page, so many of the components that use JavaScript to help with rendering attach their markup to the `<body>` tag.

Here's a super simplified version of what PrimeFaces is doing:

```
<body>
    <script>
        var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var text = document
            .createTextNode("I was created dynamically via JavaScript!"); 
        dynDiv.appendChild(text);
        document.body.appendChild(dynDiv);
    </script>
</body>
```

However, in a portlet environment, portlet only has control over the portlet markup which is a `<div>` inside the `<body>` tag. But since PrimeFaces assumes a webapp environment, it still appends markup to the `<body>`:

```
<body>
    <div id="myPrimeFacesPortlet">
        <script>
            var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
            var text = document
                .createTextNode("I was created dynamically via JavaScript!"); 
            dynDiv.appendChild(text);
            document.body.appendChild(dynDiv);
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Before Liferay 7.0, this was not a problem though since every navigation would cause a full page load and all the dynamic elements created by PrimeFaces' JavaScript would be destroyed. Now with Liferay 7.0 [the Single Page Application engine of SennaJS is used to make sure that only necessary parts of the page are loaded and rendered on navigation](https://sennajs.com/). Now when you navigate away from the PrimeFaces portlet via SennaJS all PrimeFaces CSS is removed along with the portlet `<div>`. The dynamic elements are not removed, and the PrimeFaces CSS is unloaded so it cannot hide them anymore.

#### Solutions

There are several possible solutions to this problem (I've ordered them from best to worst):

- If the component has an `appendTo` attribute, ensure that markup is appended to an element inside the portlet markup: `appendTo="@this"`, `appendTo="@id(#{portletNamespace})"` (for the outermost `<div>` of the portlet) or `appendTo="@form"` should also work (although `appendTo="@root"` does not appear to work) (see [the PF User Guide (p. 558) for more details on the "Search Expression Framework"](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf)).
- Permanently hide the dynamic elements with CSS. To ensure the CSS is not removed on SennaJS navigation, set `data-senna-track="permanent"`:

  ```
  <h:head>
      <!--You'll need to look at the CSS for each element (not just tooltip)
          to figure out what CSS classes should be hidden. -->
      <style id="hidePrimeFacesLeftoverMarkupWorkaroundCSS"
          data-senna-track="permanent">
          .ui-tooltip {
              display: none;
          }
      </style>
  </h:head>
  ```
- [Disable SennaJS for your Portlet or your entire Portal.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288039/how-can-i-disable-sennajs-spa-in-liferay-7)

#### More Info:

- https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2677
- https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/105009688
- https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/94179972